# how to change "§" (section symbol) key to write "`" (back quote)

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm using back quote many times but never use the '§' symbol.

I'd like to change the key to always write back quote instead. does anyone know how can I change it programtically?

[image]

Comment: Note that there *is* already a back quote on your keyboard (left of the Z).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md) to remap keys on your keyboard.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Section to Back quote</name>
    <identifier>sectiontobackquote</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::UK_SECTION | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::BACKQUOTE
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 18):

An easier way with **Karabiner** is to just add a new *Simple Modification* (the first tab in Karabiner):

> From: `Controls and Symbols` > `non_us_backslash`
> To: `Controls and Symbols` > `` grave_accent_and_tilde (`) ``

Here's a screenshot of that: (and for an older version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgkrI.png))

[image: Screenshot of Karabiner interface with this setting added]

---

#### Why is that called `non_us_backslash` and not `§`?

The "*non us backslash*" is probably any key directly below the <kbd>esc</kbd> key (or the touchbar) (source: [this issue](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/582)).

On the English International, UK English, Dutch, Polish etc. keyboards, that's the key that produces the section symbol `§`.