# Map Section sign (§) button to backtick(`) and tilde (~) without Karabiner

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

The question [how to change "§" (section symbol) key to write "`" (back quote)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/292928/how-to-change-section-symbol-key-to-write-back-quote) has a solution using Karabiner but I am looking for a non-Karabiner solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't just reference another question with a link. Clearly explain the problem you're facing as well as the solutions you've already tried and why they didn't work. See [ask] for info on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to make a custom layout for this.