# How to change the key § to key ` on macOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, keyboard

I would like to change the key § to key ```` on MacOS 12.6.

Not a Mac GURU, but when I type, I'm using the ` apostrophe and is much easier for me if possible.

Can someone please provide step-by-step instructions on how to do it please?

Comment: What keyboard do you have [add a photo if you're not sure] & what language layout is being used? BTW, ` is a backtick [or grave accent], not an apostrophe '

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/292928/how-to-change-section-symbol-key-to-write-back-quote?rq=1

Comment: is the UK keyboard, my pic is larger than 2MB to be uploaded. I have the GBP sign on number 3

Comment: A UK keyboard already has backtick ` immediately left of Z [unless it's a PC keyboard]

Comment: All done with Karabiner. Thanks @TomGewecke for the link